# SQL Server - Sum Time pr Day

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-express

I need some advice with some SQL queries. Currently using SQL Server Express 2016. I have two tables. Master Table is called Dive and detail table is called DiveLog. Its a system for logging events for equipment used under water in the oil and gas industry.

Below are the details of the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dives](
[DiveNo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ROVID] [smallint] NULL,
[ClientID] [int] NULL,
[ProjectID] [int] NULL,
[WorksiteID] [int] NULL,
[TaskID] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Dives] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DiveLog](
[LP] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Time] [datetime] NULL,
[Activity] [smallint] NULL,
[Comment] [varchar](max) NULL,
[DiveNo] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_DiveLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

For each dive, a new reccord in the dive table is created. During the dive, various dive events are logged. Ex:

```
Time                  Comment
2017-07-01 12:03:22 - Equipment in the water
2017-07-01 12:06:34 - Starting job
2017-07-01 15:03:55 - Job completed
2017-07-01 16:08:01 - Equipment on deck, dive complete
```

Now I need to create report of how much dive time per day for a given time period. There can be several dives per day and one dive can span over multiple days. I need to summarize dive time per day 00:00 to 24:00. Detail level is based on minutes

It should look something like this:

```
Date         Time
2017-07-01 - 23:33,
2017-07-02 - 24:00,
2017-07-03 - 01:00,
```

Or it can only be summarized in minutes and I will convert it to time in my app.

```
Date         Sum minutes
2017-07-01 - 435,
2017-07-02 - 109,
2017-07-03 - 597,
```

So obviously the max and min date per dive has to be established and then summarize it per 24 hours periods breaking at midnight

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Do you have a column that denotes the start/finish? Or a job id for that particular dive?

Comment: Please post some FULL sample data, comma or pipe delimited

Comment: Do dives ever start before midnight and finish after midnight?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: JohnHC: Sadly there is no column that donotes start / Finish. I have just taken over this app and tasked with making a new GUI. In future release I would have more control and could enforce such rules. However, the existing data only have events. When I listed the dives on the main page I had to join with the DiveLog table and use min() and max() to calculate the start and end.

Comment: Caius Jard: Dives can start before midnight and span over midnight. They can even span over several days. However, per system, there is only one dive that takes place at any given time

Comment: That last footnote throws a spanner in the works and makes things hugely more complex, if a dive can start at 23:00 on day 1, finish at 01:00 on day 3 and you're hoping to see "60, 1440, 60" as your minutes respectively

Comment: @CaiusJard. Yes, I might have to implement part of the logic's to get this right in the application as well. Anyhow, how would you recommend designing the database for the future to allow this purely in SQL? I mean, a dive can be as short as a few minutes and as long as several weeks.

Comment: It can be done purely in SQL, but it gets a bit nasty, as you have to construct an artificial list of days to join the events onto, so you get a start date on a particular day, and can detect if the end data is not that day, so you put the end time down as the end of the day instead; that way you can do a minutes calc. On the next day, the start time of the day can fill in for the start time of the dive, and the same logic applied to the end date - did it end today? no, well.. put the end date of the day down, calc the minutes (1440), move on to the next day...

Comment: We need an "artificial" list of days because on a long 3 days dive, there wouldnt be any start or end even recorded at all on day 2. If all we are looking at is start and end events, then day 2 ceases to participate in calculations because it's not part of the row set selected by something like `SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_type IN ('startdive','stopdive')` - you only get 2 rows, one for day 1 when the start occurred and one for day 3 when the stop occurred, yet on a row-by-row summing basis you need the day 2 row in the middle to participate. How would I design the system differently?..

Comment: I'd look to either do some of the math in the client, or insert dummy rows into the events table at 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 as a "dive brought forward/dive carried forward" markers - these make the SQL more tirivial but theyre essentially creating real rows to make up for having to generate artificial rows as mentioned above

Comment: I've added an "artificial rows" example to my answer - to apply it to your situation you'll still need to confirm how you can tell the difference between a start time and an end time. Your posted sample data is too skinny on detail to be able to guess this reliably

Comment: @CaiusJard. Thanks for your further explanation. As you mention, I'll do some further math in the client and redesign the db a bit for further versions once I get the permission. Again, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that ACTIVITY column is something like 'start', 'end'. If it isn't you'll have to find another way of reliably identifying which timed event is the start and which is the end:

```
SELECT
  start_times.diveno,
  SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, start_times.starttime, end_times.endtime))
FROM 
  (
    SELECT
      diveno,
      [time] as start_time,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY diveno ORDER BY [time] ASC) as start_counter
    FROM
      DiveLog
    WHERE
      activity = 'start_dive'
  ) start_times
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      diveno,
      [time] as end_time,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY diveno ORDER BY [time] ASC) as end_counter
    FROM
      DiveLog
    WHERE
      activity = 'end_dive'
  ) end_times
  ON
    start_times.diveno = end_times.diveno AND start_counter = end_counter
GROUP BY
  start_times.diveno
```

This solution assumes that 2 dive activities for a particular job do not overlap, but it might not matter: If there are two dive activities logged overlapping, and activity 1 starts at 00:02 and finishes at 00:12 (ten minutes) and activity 2 starts at 00:07 and finished at 00:09 (2 minutes) then the total is 12 minutes, this code will pair up the start of activity 1 with the end of activity 2 as if it was the end of activity 1, and record activity 1 as 7 minutes. It will then also record activity 2 as 5 minutes for similar logic.. The total is again 12 minutes, but I've a basic concern that this is mixing up start and end dates

Really your app should record activities with a dedicated activity ID also; this activity id is the same number for every entry relating to a particular activity

The "artificial days" approach looks like this (note: need a good amount of sample data to properly write it - this has all been written and never run; please let me know any errors via the comments. note2: the way the report date range would be restricted is to provide values for the parameters `@searchStartDate` - a datetime that should be midnight on the first day e.g. "2017-01-01 00:00:00" and  `@plusDaysToSearch` the number of days after this to look over e.g. 90 for the next 90 days after 2017-01-01 ):

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT @searchStartDate as d
    UNION ALL
    SELECT d + 1.0 FROM dates WHERE d < @searchStartDate + @plusDaysToSearch --cant go over 100 here without changing the recursion limit
)

SELECT
  dates.d,
  SUM(
    DATEDIFF(
      minute, 
      CASE WHEN dive_times.start_date != dates.d THEN dates.d ELSE dive_times.start_time END, 
      CASE WHEN dive_times.start_date != dates.d THEN dates.d ELSE dive_times.start_time END
    )
  ) as minutes_dived_today
FROM
  dives
  CROSS APPLY
  dates

  LEFT JOIN

  (
    SELECT start_times.diveno, start_time, start_date, end_time, end_date
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          diveno,
          [time] as start_time,
          convert(date, [time]) as start_date,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY diveno ORDER BY [time] ASC) as start_counter
        FROM
          DiveLog
        WHERE
          activity = 'start_dive'
      ) start_times
      INNER JOIN
      (
        SELECT
          diveno,
          [time] as end_time,
          convert(date, [time]) as start_date,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY diveno ORDER BY [time] ASC) as end_counter
        FROM
          DiveLog
        WHERE
          activity = 'end_dive'
      ) end_times
      ON
        start_times.diveno = end_times.diveno AND
        start_times.start_counter = end_times.end_counter
  ) dive_times
  ON 
    dives.diveno = end_times.diveno AND 
    dates.d BETWEEN dive_times.start_date AND dive_times.end_date

GROUP BY
  dates.d
```

Comment: You are almost there: 1. `[time] ASC) as end_counter` should be `[time] DESC) as end_counter`  2. you also need to partition by day as he is interested in hours per dive per day.

Comment: End counter is ASC not desc because I'm operating on the assumption that the first dive activity comes to an end before the next begins, hence a dive activity log for a day might look like: start1, finish1, start2, finish2, and I don't want to associate start1 with finish2 which is what will happen if you order by end time DESC (finish2 gets row_number of 1). Regarding the hours per dive per day, I haven't yet had an answer to what happens on dives that start at 23:00 and finish at 02:00 the next day, so these things can't reasonably be broken out to days yet. That would however, probably..

Comment: ..not as easily be done in partition by (i.e. not done at that level) as in the outer query that does the group by. There's conceptually no difference in partitioning strategy from what is currently done, and what you propose, as restarting the row numbering each day simply means you then have to join on day also; day1-1, day1-2, day2-1, day2-2 is just as fine grained as dayAll-1,dayAll-2,dayAll-3,dayAll-4 for join purposes. See what the "over midnight" query comes back with.. End times will have to ignore day within the partition if that's the case, and some extra logic in the datediff needed

Comment: @CaiuJard: I'm aware that the design of this database is far from perfect from the previous dev. Once I get permission, the first thing I will do is to make it more logical. Just to wrap it up... No dives will be overlapping and the start and stop time would have to be calculated based on min() and max() time form the detail table.